# Apache 2 Forbidden 403 Error despite "Require all granted"

Tags: apache

I am getting the apparently infamous apache 2 forbidden error #403, and I tried following the guides on the subject, but none seem to be working.
I am using Ubuntu Server and Apache 2.4.41

My website structure looks like /var/www/html/index.html

My apache2.conf [/etc/apache2/apache2.conf]:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My vhosts.conf [/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf]:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How about the permissions on directory `/var/www/html` ?

Comment: @Nic3500 how would I go about doing that? Is that a .htaccess file or something like that?

Comment: At the linux level, what are the permissions on /var/www/html ?  Make sure the user that runs apache has read and traversal (x) permission.

Comment: Great, I put it as an answer, I would appreciated it if you accepted it :)

Answer (score 0):

From an Apache standpoint, your configuration seems ok.

Please verify the permissions on your `/var/www/html` directory.  The user that runs Apache should have at least read and traversal (x) permission.

Answer (score 0):

I gave the user running Apache2 permissions to the /var/www/html folder, and was then able to access the website.

Here is a URL with several permissions, I don't know specifically which one was responsible, but I believe it was `sudo chmod g+w /var/www/html`
https://askubuntu.com/questions/767504/permissions-problems-with-var-www-html-and-my-own-home-directory-for-a-website